# SQL count + join throws syntax error, but works ok without count

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I'm getting weird syntax error with the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT (*) 
FROM a 
JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id
```

But querying without `COUNT` works like a charm:

```
SELECT * 
FROM a 
JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id
```

Adding JOIN specification like INNER, LEFT, etc - doesn't help.

> The syntax error doesn't specify exactly what's wrong, just provides certain codes: [42000][1064]

How do I fix it?

## EDIT:

Here it is:

```
SELECT COUNT(customers.*) 
FROM customers 
JOIN customer_behaviour ON customers.id = customer_behaviour.customer_id
```

Deleting `COUNT` makes it totally valid. That's really weird!

Comment: Make sure there is no space between `COUNT` and the bracket `(`, it should be `COUNT(*)`. I know the query you posted doesn't have the space, but make sure it's the same when you run it

Comment: Please do not edit question in a way that invalidates existing answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove space between `COUNT` and `(*)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id 
    -- COUNT (*)
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=744961292c26c75f21aa989062312b60)**

---

## EDIT:

```
SELECT COUNT(customers.*) 
FROM customers 
JOIN customer_behaviour 
  ON customers.id = customer_behaviour.customer_id

-- should be    
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM customers 
JOIN customer_behaviour 
  ON customers.id = customer_behaviour.customer_id

-- or
SELECT COUNT(customers.id) 
FROM customers 
JOIN customer_behaviour 
  ON customers.id = customer_behaviour.customer_id
```

## EDIT 2

> Now, can I add DISTINCT to it? Seems like using COUNT (DISTINCT ...) starts throwing the error again!

Simply by defining column name:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT table_name.column_name) 
FROM customers 
JOIN customer_behaviour 
  ON customers.id = customer_behaviour.customer_id
```

Comment: @AntonMatrosov Please post your "real" query. This syntax error is caused by `COUNT<space>(*)`

Comment: Here it is:
`SELECT COUNT(customers.*) FROM customers JOIN customer_behaviour ON customers.id = customer_behaviour.customer_id`
Deleting COUNT makes it totally valid. That's really weird!

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it!

Comment: Now, can I add DISTINCT to it? Seems like using COUNT (DISTINCT ...) starts throwing the error again!

Comment: Nevermind, using COUNT (DISTINCT customers.id) solves it.